# Java AWT in .NET

Tags: java, .net, interop

Is there an equivalent for Java [AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit) that works on .NET?

I usually use [IKVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IKVM.NET) for Java bytecode translation, but IKVM AWT support is fairly limited.

Comment: Are you looking for a Java-based GUI library that you can IKVM to .NET?  Or would a .NET-based library that has features similar to AWT?

Comment: IKVM has an JVM implementation but AWT isn't fully implemented.
I need a Java.awt .Net implementation :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net/) could help you ? Or one of the other Java to COM bridges ?

Comment: Can jni4net be used for "bridging" AWT in .net ?

Comment: Generally yes. But I never tried anything advanced. As well bear in mind that jni4net is still young and under heavy development.

Comment: Great, can you provide any general ideas on how this can be achieved as AWT isn't a jar library (How will I build the proxy class)? I will do the test drive.

Comment: It's in jre/lib/rt.jar
Best would be to filter by packages, say java.awt and sun.awt by proxygen, but that's not implemented yet. I noted it as feature request.
So for now you need to find the classes you need and create config for proxygen by hands.

Comment: You dont know how much I'd lOVE to participate in this project :)

Comment: Drop me an email, if you think you have skills and time to join.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are no implementations of AWT for .NET that are more complete than the (as you've seen) partially complete version in IKVM.  Be sure to use the latest IKVM snapshots, though, as it has improved quite a bit over the past year.

The only similar project that I know of is [Ja.NET](http://www.janetdev.org/), but I doubt their AWT is in any better shape than the one in IKVM.